# How do you initialize the Twilio Client in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor, twilio

I'm having incredible difficulty setting up the Twilio Client in Meteor JS, and would really appreciate any help.

I have extracted the relevant code and error logs below. So far as I can tell, it should be simple. The code is just grabbing an `authtoken` which I have previously generated, and then trying to set up the device using that `authtoken`. But it's not working.

```js
'click #initializeDevice'(event) {
      var thisAuthToken = Session.get('myAuthToken');
      console.log(thisAuthToken); // I have confirmed with Twilio support that these authtokens are correctly generated
      const Device = require('twilio-client').Device;
      Device.setup(thisAuthToken, { debug: true });
      var myStatus = Device.status()
      console.log(myStatus); //this is logging "offline"
      Device.on('ready',function (device) {
        log('Twilio.Device Ready!'); //this is not logging anything
      });
      },
```

When that code runs, it generates the following logs:

```
eyJhbGciDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9QVA2NDE2MzJmMzA1ZjJiY2I[Note:I have deleted part of the middle of the logged authtoken for the purpose of this public post]5YmMxOGQyOWVlNGU2ZGM0NjdmMzRiNDVhNCIsImV4cCI6MTU3Nz0ygbJKTx15GgNCWDkm-iUPjn_O1NZU6yovp4vjE
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 Setting up VSP
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 WSTransport.open() called...
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 Attempting to connect...
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 Closing and cleaning up WebSocket...
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 No WebSocket to clean up.
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 Could not connect to endpoint: ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 Closing and cleaning up WebSocket...
modules.js?hash=69069bec9aeba9503ae3467590cf182be57d9e62:3605 No WebSocket to clean up.
calltemplate.js:31 offline
```

I'm doing this all from a local server, tunneled through NGROK. I've also set up the Twilio back end, linked the app, purchased a number, etc.

So far as I can tell, the issue, from the logs, appears to be something to do with the way that Meteor uses WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not connect to endpoint: ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object

This is a not a Meteor related problem rather than browser issue.

Make sure your browser supports [WebRTC](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180848-Which-Web-Browsers-Support-WebRTC-)

BTW, Your browser might be supporting it but you'd need to enable it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help; I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I'm not sure this was the answer. I'm using google Chrome on desktop - and so far as I can tell, a recent version. Ultimately I gave up on Twilio and used Agora.io and that worked just fine with Chrome.